# How to restart naming GDB's internal variables from $1?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, scripting, gdb

By default, GDB's internal variables will be $1, $2, $3, .... How to restart naming them from $1?

```
(gdb) p v1
$1 = 7
(gdb) p v2
$2 = 8
(gdb) p v3
$3 = 9
(gdb) ??? // what should be put here?
$1 = 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-History.html#Value-History), there's no explicit command to clear the value history.

It does mention that the `file` and `symbol-file` commands, which can change the symbol table, clear the history.

Also, you can use `output` instead of `print` to avoid putting the printed value in the value history.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.  There's no way to do it.  I wonder why he wanted to do it, though.  Perhaps he's really trying to do something else.